# Kivy "module weakmethod" import error

Tags: python, kivy

I created a osx app with py2app, written in Python with Kivy, but when I open the app found the message "Appkivy Error". I have opened in terminal and found "ImportError: No module named weakmethod". Could somemone please tell me how to solve this problem?

- Python version: 2.7.14.
- Kivy version 1.10.0.
- Osx: Sierra 10.12.6

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Setup file code:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Appkivy.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Error log in terminal:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/crisflores/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-12-05_7.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 12:01:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/crisflores/Desktop/dist/Appkivy.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 386, in <module>
     _run()
   File "/Users/crisflores/Desktop/dist/Appkivy.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 370, in _run
     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
   File "/Users/crisflores/Desktop/dist/Appkivy.app/Contents/Resources/Appkivy.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "kivy/app.pyc", line 319, in <module>
   File "kivy/base.pyc", line 29, in <module>
   File "kivy/clock.pyc", line 362, in <module>
   File "kivy/_clock.pyc", line 14, in <module>
   File "kivy/_clock.pyc", line 10, in __load
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 9, in init kivy._clock
 ImportError: No module named weakmethod
2017-12-05 20:45:02.688 Appkivy[11703:496925] Appkivy Error
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I have redownloaded Kivy and py2app but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was having the same problem using the latest py2app and Kivy.  
Then I noticed that the Kivy docs actually recommend PyInstaller instead of py2app.  The instructions are rather involved, so I'll point you to them:  https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html
I have not yet been able to get this to work; many errors still occur.

Comment: I'm having pretty much the same error with PyInstaller now, after returning to my program after a while (and probably after upgrading to Linux Mint 18.3 from a previous version). The executable that I packaged before runs fine. If I package a new one now - it fails to launch with "ImportError: No module named weakmethod" in kivy._clock.
Same error with Kivy 1.9.1 and 1.10.0, and PyInstaller 3.2 and 3.3.1.
Any idea why doesn't this particular module gets properly packaged?